# ¿Cómo cambiar la forma en que se muestran los errores de Stripe en codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe

Hola compañeros esperando me puedan ayudar les resumo la consulta.

Soy nuevo completamente en esto de PHP y codeigniter.

Cómo puedo hacer que los errores de Stripe se muestren como un aviso amigable o una ventana flotante sin salir de la pantalla en que esta el comprador o regresar a la pantalla del pago con el error correspondiente.

Actualmente los errores saltan de la siguiente forma

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Stripe\Exception\CardException

Message: Your card has insufficient funds.

Filename: /home/mrva/web/chambanet.mx/public_html/application/third_party/stripe/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php

Line Number: 38

Backtrace:
```

Seguidos de muchos archivos, como ven solo indica que la tarjeta no tiene los fondos necesarios, pero de cara al usuario parece un error más grave y me gustaría saber como cambiar la forma en la que se muestra.

Trabajo sobre Ubuntu 18.04

PHP 7.2

Edito para agregar lo que solicito Marcos

order_confirmation.php

```
<!-- start banner Area -->
<section class="banner-area relative" id="home">    
    <div class="overlay overlay-bg"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="about-content col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="text-white">
                    <?=trans('order_confirmation')?>
                </h1>   
                <p class="text-white link-nav"><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>"><?=trans('back')?> </a>  <span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span>  <a href=""><?=trans('order_confirmation')?> </a></p>
            </div>                                          
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End banner Area -->
<section class="section-gap">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3>Your Order Summary</h3>
                <hr />
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">

                <div class="card">

                    <div class="card-body">

                        <h5 class="card-title"><?= $package_detail['title'] ?> &nbsp; (<span><?= $this->general_settings['currency']; ?></span> <?=$package_detail['price']?><?=($package_detail['price'] != 0)? '&nbsp;/&nbsp;'.($package_detail['title']):'';?>)</h5>

                        <p class="card-text">This package includes following features: </p>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <?=trans('no_of_posts')?>: <?= $package_detail['no_of_posts'] ?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <?=trans('no_of_days')?>: <?= $package_detail['no_of_days'] ?>
                        </p>

                        <p class="card-text">Details:
                             <?= $package_detail['detail'] ?>
                        </p>

                        <p><h4>Total Due: &nbsp;<?= $this->general_settings['currency']; ?> <?=$package_detail['price']?></h4></p>
                        <!--<p><h4>Next Expiry Date: &nbsp; $expiry_date?></h4></p> -->

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="card col-lg-5">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- Credit card form tabs -->
                    <ul role="tablist" class="nav bg-light nav-pills rounded-pill nav-fill mb-3">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a data-toggle="pill" href="#nav-tab-card" class="nav-link active rounded-pill">
                                <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                                Credit Card
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a data-toggle="pill" href="#nav-tab-paypal" class="nav-link rounded-pill">
                                <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>
                                Paypal
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <!-- End -->


                    <!-- Credit card form content -->
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <!-- credit card info-->
                        <div id="nav-tab-card" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                            <p class="payment-status" id="payment-errors">&nbsp;</p>
                            <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'paymentFrm', 'method' => 'post' , 'class' => 'form_horizontal'); ?>
                            <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url('employers/packages/pay_with_stripe'),$attributes);?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Full name (on the card)</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Jason Doe" required class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="test@example.com" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" class="form-control" value="<?= $package_detail['id'] ?>" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_price" class="form-control" value="<?= $package_detail['price'] ?>" required />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cardNumber">Card number</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="card-number" id="card-number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your card number" class="form-control" required>
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text text-muted">
                                                <i class="fa fa-cc-visa mx-1"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-cc-amex mx-1"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard mx-1"></i>
                                            </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label><span class="hidden-xs">Expiration</span></label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="number" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" name="card-expiry-month" id="card-expiry-month" class="form-control" required>
                                            <input type="number" placeholder="YY" maxlength="4" name="card-expiry-year" id="card-expiry-year" class="form-control" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                        <label data-toggle="tooltip" title="Three-digits code on the back of your card">CVV
                                            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="text" name="card-cvc" id="card-cvc" required class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="payBtn" class="subscribe btn btn-primary btn-block rounded-pill shadow-sm"> Confirm  </button>
                            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End -->

                        <!-- Paypal info -->
                        <div id="nav-tab-paypal" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <?php echo form_open(base_url('employers/packages/buy'), 'class="my-form" '); ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="package_id" value="<?=$package_detail['id']?>">
                            <p>Pay with your Paypal account.</p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill" value="Pay with Paypal">
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-muted">System will take you to Paypal website for payment.
                            </p>
                            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End -->




                    </div>
                    <!-- End -->

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

</section>

<script>
    var csfr_token_name = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>';
    var csfr_token_value = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
    var total_amount = '<?php $package_detail['price'];  ?>';
    var currency = '<?php echo 'USD'; ?>';
    var stripe_key = '<?php echo 'sk_test_TMbUaFbCy6vreanBfGa64frP00mxfxxHiv' ?>';
</script>

<!-- Stripe JavaScript library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

Packages.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');



class Packages extends Main_Controller {



    public function __construct()

    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->rbac->check_emp_authentiction(); 

        $this->load->library('paypal_lib');

        $this->load->model('employers/package_model', 'package_model');

        $this->load->model('payment_model');

    }



    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function index()

    {   

        $data['packages'] = $this->package_model->get_all_pakages();



        $data['title'] = 'Packages';

        $data['layout'] = 'employers/packages/packages_list';

        $this->load->view('layout', $data);

    }



    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function buy()

    {

        $package_id = $this->input->post('package_id');

        $package_detail = $this->package_model->get_package_by_id($package_id);



        if($package_detail['price'] == 0){

            $buyer_data = array(

            'employer_id' => emp_id(),

            'package_id' =>  $package_detail['id'],

            'expire_date' => add_days_to_date($package_detail['no_of_days']),

            'buy_date' => date('Y-m-d : h:m:s'),

            );



            if(emp_id()){

                // deactive the employer prev package

                $this->payment_model->deactive_emp_prev_package(); 

                // add new package

                $this->payment_model->insert_buyer_package($buyer_data);

                redirect(base_url('employers/dashboard'));

            }

            exit();

        }



        // Set variables for paypal form

        $returnURL = base_url().'paypal/success';

        $cancelURL = base_url().'paypal/cancel';

        $notifyURL = base_url().'paypal/ipn';

        

        

        // Add fields to paypal form

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', $returnURL);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', $cancelURL);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', $notifyURL);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name', $package_detail['title']);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number',  $package_detail['id']);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount',  $package_detail['price']);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('payer_id',  emp_id());

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('rm',  2);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('handling',  0);

        

        // Render paypal form

        $this->paypal_lib->paypal_auto_form();

    }



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function bought()

    {   

        $emp_id = $this->session->userdata('employer_id');



        $data['package_detail'] = $this->package_model->get_employer_packages($emp_id);



        $data['emp_sidebar'] = 'employers/emp_sidebar'; // load sidebar for employer

        

        $data['title'] = trans('packages');

        $data['layout'] = 'employers/packages/employer_packages_bought';

        $this->load->view('layout', $data);

    }



    public function order_confirmation()

    {

        $this->rbac->check_emp_authentiction();

        $package_id = $this->input->post('package_id');

        if($package_id == '')
        {
            redirect(base_url('employers'));
        }

        $data['package_detail'] = $this->package_model->get_package_by_id($package_id);

        $price = $data['package_detail']['price'];

        if($price == '0')
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('errors',trans('free_package_error'));
            redirect(base_url('employers/dashboard'));
        }

        $data['title'] = trans('order_confirmation');

        $data['layout'] = 'employers/packages/order_confirmation';

        $this->load->view('layout', $data);

    }



    public function pay_with_stripe()

    {

        /*

        4242424242424242 – Visa

        4000056655665556 – Visa (debit)

        5555555555554444 – Mastercard

        5200828282828210 – Mastercard (debit)

        378282246310005 – American Express

        6011111111111117 – Discover

        */

        $item_number = $this->input->post('item_number');

        $package_detail = $this->package_model->get_package_by_id($item_number);



        if($package_detail['price'] == 0){

            $buyer_data = array(

                'employer_id' => emp_id(),

                'package_id' =>  $package_detail['id'],

                'expire_date' => add_days_to_date($package_detail['no_of_days']),

                'buy_date' => date('Y-m-d : h:m:s')

            );



            if(emp_id()){

                // deactive the employer prev package

                $this->payment_model->deactive_emp_prev_package();

                // add new package

                $insert_buyer_pkg = $this->payment_model->insert_buyer_package($buyer_data);

                if(($insert_buyer_pkg)){

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Package updated successfully.');

                } else {

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', 'Error while updating pacakge in local database');

                }

                redirect(base_url('employers/dashboard'));

            }

            exit();

        }



        //check whether stripe token is not empty

        if(!empty($this->input->post('stripeToken')))

        {

            //get token, card and user info from the form

            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

            $token  = $this->input->post('stripeToken');

            $name = $this->input->post('name');

            $email = $this->input->post('email');

            $card_num = $this->input->post('card-number');

            $card_cvc = $this->input->post('card-cvc');

            $card_exp_month = $this->input->post('card-expiry-month');

            $card_exp_year = $this->input->post('card-expiry-year');



            //include Stripe PHP library

            require_once APPPATH."third_party/stripe/init.php";



            //set api key

            $this->CI =& get_instance();

            $stripe_secret_key = $this->CI->general_settings['stripe_secret_key'];

            $stripe_publish_key = $this->CI->general_settings['stripe_publish_key'];

            $stripe = array(

                "secret_key"      => $stripe_secret_key,

                "publishable_key" => $stripe_publish_key

            );



            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);



            //add customer to stripe

            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(

                'email' => $email,

                'source'  => $token

            ));



            //item information



            $item_price = $this->input->post('item_price');

            // $domain_list = $this->input->post('domain_list');

            $currency = "MXN";



            //charge a credit or a debit card

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(

                'customer' => $customer->id,

                'amount'   => $item_price,

                'currency' => $currency,

                'description' => $item_number,

                'metadata' => array(

                    'item_id' => $item_number

                )

            ));



            //retrieve charge details

            $chargeJson = $charge->jsonSerialize();



            //check whether the charge is successful

            if($chargeJson['amount_refunded'] == 0 && empty($chargeJson['failure_code']) && $chargeJson['paid'] == 1 && $chargeJson['captured'] == 1)

            {

                //order details

                $amount = $chargeJson['amount'];

                $balance_transaction = $chargeJson['balance_transaction'];

                $currency = $chargeJson['currency'];

                $status = $chargeJson['status'];

                $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");



                // Save payment data into DB



                if(emp_id())

                    $emp_id = emp_id();

                else

                    $emp_id = 0;



                if(user_id())

                    $user_id = user_id();

                else

                    $user_id = 0;



                $payment_data = array(

                    'payment_method' => 'stripe',

                    'txn_id' => $balance_transaction,

                    'employer_id' => $emp_id,

                    'user_id' => $user_id,

                    'currency' => strtoupper($currency),

                    'payment_amount' => $amount,

                    'payer_email' => $email,

                    'payment_status' => $status,

                    'purchased_plan' => $item_number,

                    'payment_date' => $date,

                );



                $payment_id = $this->payment_model->insert_payment($payment_data);

                $no_of_days = get_package_days($item_number);



                $buyer_data = array(

                    'payment_id' => $payment_id,

                    'employer_id' => $emp_id,

                    'user_id' => $user_id,

                    'package_id' =>  $item_number,

                    'expire_date' => add_days_to_date($no_of_days),

                    'buy_date' => $date,



                );



                if(emp_id()){

                    $this->payment_model->deactive_emp_prev_package(); // deactive the employer prev package on buying new package

                    $this->payment_model->insert_buyer_package($buyer_data);

                    if(($payment_id) && $status == 'succeeded'){

                        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Payment has been paid successfully.');

                    } else if ($status == 'succeeded'){

                        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', 'Payment paid. Error while saving payment data at local database');

                    }

                    redirect(base_url('employers/dashboard'));

                }



                if(user_id()){

                    // sending invoice to user

                    //$user_info = get_user_by_id(user_id());

                    $this->payment_model->deactive_user_prev_package(); // deactive the employer prev package on buying new package

                    $this->payment_model->insert_buyer_package($buyer_data);

                    redirect(base_url('user/dashboard'));

                }

            }

            else

            {

                $package_id = $this->input->post('item_number');

                $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', 'Invalid Token');

                redirect(base_url('employers', 'refresh'));

            }

        } else {

            echo 'invalid stripe token';exit;

        }

    }



}// endClass
```

Como les comente soy nuevo en esto y aunque no le tengo miedo al codigo tampoco se muy bien por donde empezar, leeré los recursos que me brindo Augusto, gracias :)

Comment: Usa el Stripe JS SDK para que Stripe muestre los errores en pantalla de forma amigable del lado del cliente

Comment: Aqui puedes encontrar informacion de como implementarlo: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Comment: @AugustoM, este es el SDK para PHP, aunque puede la solución puede que se asemeje la sintaxis es distinta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es manejando las excepciones con [`try/catch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
public function pay_with_stripe()
{

    // ... Código anterior ...

    $error = ''; // Bandera para verificar si fallo
    try {

        //charge a credit or a debit card

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'amount'   => $item_price,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'description' => $item_number,
            'metadata' => array(
                'item_id' => $item_number
            )
        ));
    }
    catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
      // Si la tarjeta es rechazada, \Stripe\Exception\CardException
      $error = $e->getError()->message . '\n';
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
      // Demasiadas solicitudes realizadas a la API demasiado rápido
      $error = $e->getError()->message . '\n';
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
      // Se proporcionaron parámetros no válidos a la API de Stripe
      $error = $e->getError()->message . '\n';
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
      // Falló la autenticación con la API de Stripe
      $error = $e->getError()->message . '\n';
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
      // La comunicación de red con Stripe falló
      $error = $e->getError()->message . '\n';
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
      // Muestre un error muy genérico al usuario y tal vez envíe
       // usted mismo un correo electrónico
      $error = $e->getError()->message . '\n';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      // Algo más sucedió, completamente ajeno a Stripe.
      $error = $e->getError()->message . '\n';
    }
   
    if ($error != '') {
        echo $error;
        exit;
    }

    // ... Resto del código ...
}
```

---

Referencias:

- [Stripe - Handling errors](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling)

Comment: realice una edicion al final de la pregunta no se si así este bien?

Comment: entiendo y como me recomendarías integrarlo disculpa mi ignorancia de verdad pero no se como integrarlo

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez, he actualizado mi respuesta. Tene en cuenta que es un ejemplo, vos podes hacerlo de la forma que mejor se ajuste a tu proyecto.

Comment: definitivamente me ayudo ahora muestra solo el mensaje de error en una pantalla blanca, pero es mejor a que se muestre como antes, seguiré investigando como hacerle para que se regrese a la pagina donde se capturan los datos de la tarjeta y muestre el error en una especie de mensaje emergente, muchas gracias :)